# MySQL Subquery Count Using DATE_FORMAT alias

Tags: mysql, count, subquery, alias, date-format

I've been banging my head against the wall for the past hours trying to get this single query to work but having no success.

I have a single table called viewer_log.

Each row is a pageview with a session_id and timestamp attached to it.

I am having troubles formatting the timestamp to a day, grouping by that day, but then counting the number of UNIQUE sessions per day.

So far, for that query (which also took a long time to get working) is:

```
SELECT day, COUNT(*) as unique_sessions from (SELECT COUNT(viewer_session_id) AS sessions, DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d") AS day FROM viewer_log GROUP BY `viewer_session_id` HAVING day='2011-03-23') AS sessions;
```

You will notice the day is hardcoded, giving

```
mysql> SELECT day, COUNT(*) as unique_sessions from (SELECT COUNT(viewer_session_id) AS sessions, DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d") AS day FROM viewer_log GROUP BY `viewer_session_id` HAVING day='2011-03-23') AS sessions;
+------------+-----------------+
| day        | unique_sessions |
+------------+-----------------+
| 2011-03-23 |              21 |
+------------+-----------------+
```

I would like to expand these results without having to specify the day, which is where I am running into problems and not able to find an answer on the internet... I'm sure it's out there, not sure what I'm looking for.

EG:

```
+------------+-----------------+
| day        | unique_sessions |
+------------+-----------------+
| 2011-03-21 |              14 |
| 2011-03-22 |              11 |
| 2011-03-23 |              21 |
+------------+-----------------+
```

I am having lots of trouble moving past this point, I have tried joining the table with a copy of its self but usually run into an unknown column name OR the results I THINK should be showing up are wrong:

```
mysql> select DATE_FORMAT(v.timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d") AS date, count(sessions) as rows from (SELECT COUNT(viewer_session_id) AS sessions, DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d") AS date FROM viewer_log GROUP BY viewer_session_id) AS s JOIN viewer_log v ON (s.date=date) GROUP BY date;

+------------+--------+
| date       | rows   |
+------------+--------+
| 0000-00-00 |   2551 |
| 0000-00-00 |  20408 |
| 0000-00-00 |  20408 |
| 0000-00-00 |   5102 |
| 0000-00-00 |   2551 |
| 0000-00-00 |   2551 |
| 0000-00-00 |  63775 |
| 0000-00-00 | 211733 |
| 0000-00-00 |  53571 |
| 0000-00-00 |  53571 |
| 0000-00-00 |  53571 |
| 0000-00-00 |  51020 |
| 0000-00-00 |  48469 |
| 0000-00-00 |  91836 |
| 0000-00-00 |  86734 |
| 0000-00-00 |  33163 |
| 0000-00-00 |  45918 |
| 0000-00-00 |  28061 |
| 0000-00-00 |  86734 |
| 0000-00-00 |  76530 |
| 0000-00-00 |  53571 |
| 0000-00-00 |  33163 |
+------------+--------+
22 rows in set, 1 warning (0.63 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
  SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS day,
         COUNT(0) as unique_sessions
    FROM viewer_log
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp), viewer_session_id
```

You can add a WHERE condition like

```
  SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS day,
         COUNT(0) as unique_sessions
    FROM viewer_log
   WHERE DATE(timestamp) >= '2011-03-01'
     AND DATE(timestamp) <= '2011-03-21'
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp), viewer_session_id
```

This is assuming the timestamp is a mysql timestamp and not a unix timestamp

Comment: Thanks!  What I ended up doing was:

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, modifying your suggestion what I ended up doing was:

```
mysql> SELECT day, COUNT(*) AS unique_sessions FROM (SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS day, COUNT(0) as unique_sessions FROM viewer_log GROUP BY day, viewer_session_id) as blah GROUP BY blah.day ORDER BY day DESC;
+------------+-----------------+
| day        | unique_sessions |
+------------+-----------------+
| 2011-03-24 |              14 |
| 2011-03-23 |              23 |
| 2011-03-22 |              30 |
| 2011-03-21 |              35 |
| 2011-03-20 |              11 |
| 2011-03-19 |              18 |
| 2011-03-18 |              15 |
| 2011-03-17 |              34 |
| 2011-03-16 |              37 |
| 2011-03-15 |              21 |
| 2011-03-14 |              20 |
| 2011-03-13 |              21 |
| 2011-03-12 |              21 |
| 2011-03-11 |              21 |
| 2011-03-10 |              84 |
| 2011-03-09 |              26 |
| 2011-03-07 |               1 |
| 2011-03-05 |               1 |
| 2011-03-04 |               2 |
| 2011-03-03 |               9 |
| 2011-03-02 |               9 |
| 0000-00-00 |               1 |
+------------+-----------------+
```

Cheers!